# Whats is better: android version info in manifest.xml or gradle?

Tags: android

In my applicantion I want use app version for 'whats news dialoag', 'about',...

Is better put android version info in manifest file or in gradle?

Comment: You could keep it in both places but it's required to be in build.gradle file.

Comment: @Seishin: "it's required to be in build.gradle file" -- no, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle has facility to specify minimum and target sdk versions as well as compile version options, so you need not place the same in manifest. Gradle will merge and update manifest on build. This does not means one cannot place these attributes in manifest. So it depends on your needs. Some build automation and test tools look for manifest entries by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gradle along with the manifest, I believe Gradle will ignore anything you put in the manifest, and instead overwrite it with the values specified in gradle. I reccomend Gradle for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

definitely gradle. Gradle will automatically edit the `manifest.xml` for you

This gives you programmatic control of your manifest. Then you can do things like dynamically edit your `manifest.xml` based on the build variant, if you wanted.